# HTML5 Canvas Fading line on mouse move

Tags: javascript, canvas

I accomplished to fade a line with this code

```
function fadeOut(ctx, canvas) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  setTimeout(() => fadeOut(ctx, canvas), 50);
}
```

But the problem with this type of fading is, it fills the transparent background with a color and this cause the background div to fade as well.

The type of fading I would like to achieve is on gartic.io's background canvas.

You can check [gartic.io](https://gartic.io)

Comment: One way would be to `getImageData()` the canvas, fade every pixel out a bit, then `putImageData()` it back, but depending on the size of the canvas, that might prove too heavy.

Comment: Looking at the (minified) source on Gartic, they're just drawing the line anew on each frame, not fading out the entire canvas. (https://gartic.io/_next/static/3FKNjGfBI3huGzGLrWUKk/pages/_app.js – search for `fundo`, the ID of the canvas)

Comment: If I draw over them, some problem appears. Even the stroke weights are same, some areas they seem they are not and the background image erases by the lines.

https://prnt.sc/1zo56ub

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of that image link, sorry.